# Combine all Values from List Model into one string

Tags: string, qt, qml, listmodel

I have the following:

```
ListModel {
  id: myModel
  ListElement {
    name: "Number1"
  {
  ListElement {
    name: "Number2"
  {
  ListElement {
    name: "Number3"
  {
}
```

I want to define a variable that combines all of the "name" fields into a comma delimited string, but I have to do it within a for loop as I frequently append new elements to "myModel". Something like this:

```
property var stringOutput = ""
for (var i = 0; i < ListModel.length; ++i) {
  stringOutput = stringOutput + "," + ListModel[i].name
}
```

Resulting in:

```
stringOutput = "Number1,Number2,Number3"
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to read the [ListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) documentation?  `for (var i = 0; i < myModel.count; i++) { stringOutput += (stringOutput  === "" ? "" : ",") + myModel.get(i).name; }`